# Passing Parameters from SSRS 2008 R2 to DB2 iSeries

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2, db2-400

I need to pass parameters from SSRS 2008 R2 to DB2. We are using the DB2 I-Series 5, Version 6, Release 1. We are using OLE DB in SSRS. We have a link server set up for connecting from SQL Server to the iSeries. Either passing parameters directly to DB2 from a data set or via a stored procedure that I will create in SQL Server will do. How can this be done? If I create a stored procedure, I need to pass multiple parameters (@NameofParameter) via OpenQuery. Please create sample query and be specific about the syntax.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from connecting directly to DB2 from SSRS? Also, creating the sample query is up to you :) Provide a query with hardcoded values and we'll parameterize.